# ObjectDisposedException

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Tenho o seguinte trecho de código:

```
var nivel = 1;
List<meuObjeto> meusObjetos = new List<meuObjeto>();

using(var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext)
{
   var cmd = string.Format(@"SELECT *
                             FROM meuObjeto
                             WHERE meuObjetoNivel = {0}", nivel);

   meusObjetos.AddRange(objectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<meuObjeto>(cmd).ToList());
}
```

O problema é que ao tentar acessar qualquer objeto da lista `meusObjetos` fora do contexto do `using` recebo a exception com a seguinte descrição:

> **ObjectDisposedException**
>
> A instância de ObjectContext foi descartada e não pode mais ser usada
>   para operações que exijam uma conexão.

Até consigo aceitar que por `ObjectContext` implementar a interface `IDisposable` ao sair do contexto do `using` os dados dele não estejam mais acessíveis, mas como então posso fazer com que meus objetos fiquem 'independentes" do `ObjectContext` e permaneçam existindo mesmo após o `Dispose()` dele, mantendo assim o `using`?

Comment: O problema é que você está adicionando uma referência aos dados em `objectContext` e não fazendo uma cópia deles.

Comment: exato, mas existe alguma forma de fazer a cópia deles de forma prática?

Comment: Legal isso, hein? :) Acho pouco provável que ajude mas tentou jogar em uma variável, mesmo que seja só para testar, e só depois jogar na lista? Faça o teste tentando acessa a variável fora do `using`. Se der, aí tenta a lista.

Comment: @bigown não consegui entender direito o que você quis dizer...

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente, a lista não foi materializada no `.ToList()`, então teremos que ser mais assertivos com o contexto para obtermos uma lista materializada de fato:

```
using(var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext)
{
   var cmd = string.Format(@"SELECT *
                             FROM meuObjeto
                             WHERE meuObjetoNivel = {0}", nivel);

   var objetosMaterializados = objectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<meuObjeto>(cmd).ToList();
   meusObjetos.AddRange(objetosMaterializados);
}
```

Comment: pois é grande @CiganoMorrisonMendez o .ToList() já era pra ter materializado correto?

Comment: Depende, sobretudo porque essa abordagem só materializa a lista no último momento possível.